# Internal Server Error when retrieving revisions for some files

Tags: google-drive-api

Right now, this always happens in read-only (i.e. user has view only access) Google spreadsheets. I'm not sure what the expected response is, but the status should be at least a 4XX error and not a 5XX. Because with a server error, it's possible that it's just a temporary error that should be retried later, but in this case the status is always 500.

For read-only documents, retrieving the revisions work fine.

Comment: can you share one of those requests and the corresponding response?

Comment: I can consistently reproduce it with read-only spreadsheets. Just create a spreadsheet in one account, then share it with "View only" permissions to another. The other account, when retrieving the revisions list, will get a 500 error. The body has the reason "internalError". If you can't reproduce it, I can provide you an ID.

Comment: I managed to reproduce it, thanks. I'll file an internal bug